# 2 ресурса в try wirh resources

Tags: java

У меня есть следующий код:

```java
try (PreparedStatement ps =  databaseService.getConnection()
    .prepareStatement(Query.SELECT_IS_ACTIVE)
) {
    ps.setString(1, "some");

    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {

        // do something
    }
}
```

Мне сказали что я могу закрыть оба ресурса одним `try`, но я не знаю как. Есть идеи?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У меня вложенный try, а нужно как-то закрыть оба ресурса одним try

Comment: Какая версия Java?

Comment: У меня 8-я версия java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это классическая проблема (см. [вопрос на основном SO от 2011 года](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066501/how-should-i-use-try-with-resources-with-jdbc)), и показанное решение вполне корректно.

Альтернативный *нестрогий* вариант: использовать отдельный метод для создания заполнения параметров `PreparedStatement`, но он не гарантирует закрытия экземпляра `PreparedStatement` в гипотетическом случае:

```java
try (PreparedStatement ps = populatePreparedStatement(
    databaseService.getConnection().prepareStatement(Query.SELECT_IS_ACTIVE),
    "some");
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()
) {
    // do something
}

// ...

private PreparedStatement populatePreparedStatement(
    PreparedStatement ps, String sParam) throws SQLException {
    // если здесь будет выброшено исключение, ps не будет закрыт
    ps.setString(1, sParam);
    return ps;
}
```

---

Ещё одна альтернатива: сгенерировать готовый SQL запрос самостоятельно, *не используя* методы `PreparedStatement`:

```java
try (PreparedStatement ps = databaseService.getConnection()
    .prepareStatement(buildQuery(Query.SELECT_IS_ACTIVE, "some"));
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()
) {
    // do something
}

// ...
static String buildQuery(String query, Object ... params) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(query);
    int pos = sb.indexOf("?");
    for (Object p : params) {
        if (pos < 0) break;
        
        sb.deleteCharAt(pos);
        boolean isChar = p instanceof String || p instanceof Character;
        if (isChar) sb.insert(pos, '\'');
        sb.insert(pos, p);
        if (isChar) sb.insert(pos, '\'');
        
        pos = sb.indexOf("?", pos);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```